# Isolate first result of row in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I think I am forgetting a simple formatting button but basically I have data like 

`x   1
x   2
x   3
x   4
x   5
x   6
x   7
y   8
y   9
y   10
y   11
y   12
y   13
z   14
z   15
z   16
z   17
z   18
z   19
z   20`

How would I isolate the first X, Y, and Z cells, giving me the numbers 1, 8, and 14? etc.
So every new piece of text (i.e. A, b, c) it would isolate only the first row that contained the new content.

Comment: Use **VLOOKUP()** to retrieve the first numeric value associated with any letter.

Comment: unfortunately the numbers in the actual sheet are totally random, and I need to isolate the letter cells, in order to get numbers.

Comment: How is the dataset sorted? Will the letter column always be sorted ascending?

Comment: `VLOOKUP` should do exactly what you ask. Unless you are not asking for what you want, in which case you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54189408/edit) to clarify

Comment: Yes I just checked and it seems vlookup will work!